# Enforcing at least one field to be filled in

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table as follows:

```
[ArticleId] int NOT NULL
[AssetId] int NULL
[VideoId] int NULL
```

Both `VideoId` and `AssetId` are nullable, but I was wondering if there is a way to enforce that at least one is populated?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add a constraint that check that at least one is not null

```
ALTER TABLE YourTable 
ADD CONSTRAINT AtLeastOneFilled 
CHECK (ArticleId IS NOT NULL OR AssetId IS NOT NULL OR VideoId IS NOT NULL );
```